# Auto layout isn't working as expected for laying out buttons?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, autolayout

I'm creating a scene in **XCode** in **Main.storyboard** where the user is able to choose between 5 options (**buttons**) and when I created the auto layout to **horizontally center** the buttons, as well as **vertically space** them **5 pixels** apart:

On the **3.5 inch screen**, the buttons take up **most** of the screen

On the **4 inch screen**, the buttons take up about **3/4** of the screen

On the **4.7 inch screen**, the buttons take up about **half** of the screen

It makes sense for this to be happening, but I created a **@3x**, **@2x**, and **normal sized (1x)** images using **Prepo**

The buttons have **custom** background image properties

How can I get the **4 inch**, **4.5 inch**, and even **5.5 inch** screens on the iPhone to display like the **3.5 inch** screen where the buttons take up **most** of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Set the following constraints for your buttons.

1. For 1st button set constant top space to top layout guide (say 20px).
2. For last button set constant bottom space to bottom layout guide (say 20px).
3. Set equal heights for all buttons.

And you already have the following constraints.

1. align buttons horizontally centre
2. vertical spacing between them is 5px

So now buttons will adjust its height to take up most of screen space.
Try this.

Comment: When I do this, it makes the top button background image stretched vertically, what do you think?

Comment: I redid the constrains on the buttons like you said, but it doesn't fix, and it makes sense. If you think about it, why would a **50px x 50px** button that fits on a **4.7 inch** screen evenly fit on a **3.5 inch** screen if the button images are the equal to the original **50px x 50px** amount? I'm not saying by buttons are **50px x 50px** I'm just using that as an example.

Comment: So the buttons are resizing their height to fit on screen.And the problem is background images are getting stretched, right?

Comment: So if you want constant width and height for buttons and spacing between buttons should change as per screen height, then remove all the given constraints and try this.

1. Add holder views for all buttons and set all the 5 constraints specified in the answer for these holders. 
2.Set constant height and width constraint for buttons.
3. Add ‘centre horizontally in container’ and ‘centre vertically in container’ constraints for buttons.